# Runtime error 438 while importing data in excel from secured website using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, import, runtime-error

I am trying to import some data in MS excel from a website (login ID & password have been provided to me) using following VBA code (downloaded from other website)

```
Sub GetTable()

 Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
 Dim ieDoc As Object
 Dim ieTable As Object
 Dim clip As DataObject

 'create a new instance of ie
 Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

 'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
 ieApp.Visible = True

 'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
 ieApp.Navigate "http://cms.indianrail.gov.in/CMSREPORT/JSP/rpt/LoginAction.do?hmode=loginPage"
 Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
 Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

 Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

 'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
 With ieDoc.forms(0)
    .userType.Value = "1"
     .userId.Value = "rlbdgs"
     .userPassword.Value = "123"
     .submit
 End With
 Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
 Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

 'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
 ieApp.Navigate "http://cms.indianrail.gov.in/CMSREPORT/JSP/rpt/LoginAction.do?hmode=login"
 Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
 Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

 'get the table based on the table’s id
 Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
 Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("sampletable")

 'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
 If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
     Set clip = New DataObject
     clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
     clip.PutInClipboard
     Sheet1.Select
     Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
     Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
 End If

 'close 'er up
 ieApp.Quit
 Set ieApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

While i am trying to run the Code, I am getting 'Runtime error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method' at this area

```
 With ieDoc.forms(0)
    .userType.Value = "1"
     .userId.Value = "rlbdgs"
     .userPassword.Value = "123"
     .submit
 End With
```

Source code of login page is as under:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Report User Login</title>
    <link href="../styles/loginStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    javascript:window.history.forward(1);
    function trim(str)
    {
    return str.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,"");
    }


    function getUserType()
    {   
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
    {       
        if (localStorage.userType)
        {               
            document.forms[0].userType[localStorage.userType].checked = true ;
            if (localStorage.userType == '0')
            {
                document.forms[0].userId.value="";
                document.forms[0].userPassword.value="";
            }
            else
            {
                document.forms[0].userId.value="";
                document.forms[0].userPassword.value="";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.forms[0].userType[0].checked = true ;
            document.forms[0].userId.value="";
            document.forms[0].userPassword.value="";
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        localStorage.userType = "0";
        //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
        //alert("Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...");
    }
     }

     function setUserType(thisObj)
     {      
    localStorage.userType = thisObj.value;
    if (localStorage.userType == '0')
    {
        document.forms[0].userId.value="";
        document.forms[0].userPassword.value="";
    }
    else
    {
        document.forms[0].userId.value="";
        document.forms[0].userPassword.value="";
    }
     }

     function callAction()
     {      
    document.forms[0].action ="../../JSP/rpt/LoginAction.do?hmode=login";
    document.forms[0].submit();     

     }
     </script>

      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <link href="../styles/links.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="../styles/text.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>

      <body onLoad="getUserType();" bgcolor="#e3e3e3" >
      <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
      //alert('screen.width:'+screen.width)
      if (screen.width < 499 || screen.height < 499) {
    alert('Your Resolution: ' + screen.width + ' X ' + screen.height + '. This Application can only be run on Resolution: >= 499 X 499.')
    document.location = "/M";
      }
      //-->
     </script>
     <form name="reportLoginForm" method="post" action="/CMSREPORT/JSP/rpt/LoginAction.do">
      <table width="800" height="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
    <td width="800" height="2" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
    <td height="" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="1" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="497" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img width="497" height="200" src="images/backimage.jpg"/> </td>


<td width="1" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="30" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#333333">&nbsp;<font color="white" size="4">CMS REPORT LOGIN</font>
                                        </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="170" align="left" valign="top"><form>
              <table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td height="35" colspan="3" align="left" valign="middle">
                  <input type="radio" name="userType" value="0" onclick="setUserType(this);"><i>MOBILE/REPORT USER</i>
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="userType" value="1" onclick="setUserType(this);"><i>LOBBY/DIVISION/ZONE USER</i>
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="userType" value="2" onclick="setUserType(this);"><i>KIOSK CREW LOGIN</i>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td height="17" colspan="3" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="80" align="center" valign="middle"><i><b>USER ID:</b></i></td>
                  <td width="2" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td width="200" align="left" valign="top"><input type="text" name="userId" value=""></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="15" colspan="3" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="middle"><i><b>PASSWORD:</b></i></td>
                  <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="password" name="userPassword" value=""></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3" align="left" valign="top"><b><i><font color="red"><br/>
                        </font>
                    </i>
                    </b><script type="text/javascript">document.write('Resolution: '+screen.width+' X '+screen.height)</script>
                    <a href="/CMSTEST"></a></td>
                  </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#333333">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#333333">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td height="36" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#333333"><input type="submit" name="hmode" value="Login" onclick="return callAction();"></td>
                </tr>

                </table>
            </form></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td width="1" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></td>
        <td height="2" colspan="3" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></td>
        <td colspan="3" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table width="798" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td><table width="798" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="300"><table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="300" height="50" align="left" valign="top"><img src="images/news.jpg" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="150" align="left" valign="top"><table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td height="160" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><div id="sld">
                  <marquee  behavior="scroll" width="300px;" height="150px;" scrollamount="3" direction="up">
                   Welcome to CMS Report Login Page. Now you have to enter user id and password to see CMS Reports.
                    </marquee>
                </div></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
                <td width="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="center" valign="top"><h1 class="text" align="center"><b>Welcome To CMS</b></h1>                  
                  <p class="text">CMS project was started in 2005 with a dedicated team of 5 fresh software developers. With the passage of time the CMS system has bloomed out with the support of over 25 dedicated software engineers contributing in it's development. Leaders in the software industry like IBM, HCL, ITI, Redhat, MIND, Neoware, VXL, Anologics, Parrus IT, Palas, 3M have been contributing their resources in it's development.
                                    At present the software has Freight, Shunter, Coaching, SMS, Loco Inspector, QUICK and many more modules in use. New immerging technologies and challenges like Remote Management of the thin client from a centralised location and time syncing of all the clients to one time standard have been adopted in the CMS system.
                                    The project has been spread out to entire Indian Railways with nearly 300 lobby location and is used by over one lakh users regularly. The team has taken a leap forward by launching Electrical Loco management software in June 2009 on Jhansi Division. The Electrical Loco management software is being developed by the same team and is likely to be fully developed by June 2010.  
                  </p>
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What changes required in VBA code? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (TRIED AND TESTED)

Replace

```
With ieDoc.forms(0)
   .userType.Value = "1"
    .UserId.Value = "rlbdgs"
    .userPassword.Value = "123"
    .submit
End With
```

with

```
With ieDoc
    .getElementById("userId").setAttribute "value", "rlbdgs"
    .getElementById("userPassword").setAttribute "value", "123"

    '~~> This will select the 2nd radio button as it is `0` based
    .getElementsByName("userType")(1).Checked = True

    .getElementById("hmode").Click
End With
```