# Unable to import data in excel from another website using VB code

Tags: vba, excel, import, runtime-error

I am try to import some data in excel from a website using VB code. During course of testing first got error 438 in login section which was rectified by respected Mr. Siddharth Rout (Thanks again) through my earlier question [Runtime error 438 while importing data in excel from secured website using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263769/runtime-error-438-while-importing-data-in-excel-from-secured-website-using-vba). Now i am facing error 438 in following section and unable to import data / excel sheet remain blank.

```
'get the table based on the table’s id
     Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
     Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("report-table")

     'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to the sheet
     If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
         Set clip = New DataObject
         clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
         clip.PutInClipboard
         Sheet1.Select
         Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
         Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
     End If
```

Complete code is as under:

```
Sub GetTable()

     Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
     Dim ieDoc As Object
     Dim ieTable As Object
     Dim clip As DataObject

     'create a new instance of ie
     Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

     'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
     ieApp.Visible = True

     'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
     ieApp.Navigate "http://cms.indianrail.gov.in/CMSREPORT/JSP/rpt/LoginAction.do?hmode=loginPage"
     Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
     Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

     Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

     'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
     With ieDoc
    .getElementById("userId").setAttribute "value", "rlbdgs"
    .getElementById("userPassword").setAttribute "value", "123"

    '~~> This will select the 2nd radio button as it is `0` based
    .getElementsByName("userType")(1).Checked = True

    .getElementById("hmode").Click
     End With
     Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
     Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

     'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
     ieApp.Navigate "http://cms.indianrail.gov.in/CMSREPORT/JSP/rpt/GeneralReportAction.do?hmode=drillDown25And26And30GeneralReport&kioskOrManual=K&val=26&wherePart=ZONE_CODE_C=-IR-&lobby=AJJ&type=B&startDate=&endDate=&traction=ELEC"
     Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
     Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

     'get the table based on the table’s id
     Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
     Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("report-table")

     'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to the sheet
     If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
         Set clip = New DataObject
         clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
         clip.PutInClipboard
         Sheet1.Select
         Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
         Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
     End If

     'close 'er up
     ieApp.Quit
     Set ieApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Source code of webpage containing table (from data to be downloded) is as

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CREW BOOKED ON TA</title>

<link href="../styles/reportStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function DoNav(theUrl)
  {
    //alert(theUrl);
    document.location.href = theUrl;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="report-table">
    <!-- Table header -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="date" style="border:0px;" colspan="10">Print Date Time: <span>14-08-2014 13:30</span></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"  class="report-cris" style="text-align:center;">CRIS</th><th scope="col" class="report-heading" style="text-align:center;" colspan="8">VIGILENCE CONTROL DEVICE (VCD) IN LOCO NOT WORKING(SIGN OFF THROUGH KIOSK)(LOCO SHED WISE)(LAST 24 HOURS)<th scope="col"  class="report-cris" style="text-align:center;">CMS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border:none;">
                <th colspan="9" style="border-right:none;">
                                <span class="report-button" onclick="javascript:history.back();">BACK</span>
                                <span class="report-button" onclick="javascript:window.print();">PRINT</span>
                </th>
                <th style="border-left:none;text-align:right;"></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <table id="report-table">
    <thead>
        <tr style="border:none;" align="center">
                <th>S.No.</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>SIGNOFF DATE</th>
                <th>FROM</th>
                <th>TO</th>             
                <th>LOCO NO.</th>
                <th>BASE SHED</th>
                <th>RAILWAY</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>                              
                        <td>BINA1482</td>
                        <td >RAKESH KUMAR BAJPAI</td>
                        <td>14-08-2014 11:07</td>
                        <td >BINA</td>
                        <td>ET  </td>                       
                        <td>23551   </td>
                        <td>BRC</td>
                        <td>WR  </td>                       
                    </tr>                   

            </tbody>
</table>
* If duration for this report is last 24 hours or from and to date is same, then only last VCD reporting of the loco will be shown.
</body>
</html>
```

Please help once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this to work by replacing

```
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("report-table")
```

with

```
Set ieTable = ieDoc.getElementById("report-table")
```

Looks like the Item method returns a DispHtmlElementCollection - that doesn't support the outerHtml property. The getElementById instead returns an HTMLTable element

Comment: Sir there is two table IDs same as "report-table".  Values of only first table is being copied on excel sheet. How to workaround for second table ID also?