# Importing data using VBA in excel from webpage having 2 tables with same ID

Tags: html, vba, excel, import

First of all I would like to thanks Mr. Siddharth Rout & IAmDranged for solve the issues related to importing data in excel from secure websiteusing VBA as discussed my previous questions viz. [Runtime error 438 while importing data in excel from secured website using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263769/runtime-error-438-while-importing-data-in-excel-from-secured-website-using-vba?lq=1) and [Unable to import data in excel from another website using VB code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303193/unable-to-import-data-in-excel-from-another-website-using-vb-code?lq=1). The code is now working perfectly but there is one more issue i.e. webpage, from where i am trying to import data, have two tables with same ID "report-table". Using the VBA code is able to copy data from first table only. What modification is required in VBA for copying data from both tabels (same ID) simultaneously table. VBA code and target webpage source code are once again posted below.

```
Sub GetTable()

     Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
     Dim ieDoc As Object
     Dim ieTable As Object
     Dim clip As DataObject

     'create a new instance of ie
     Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

     'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
     ieApp.Visible = True

     'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
     ieApp.Navigate "http://cms.indianrail.gov.in/CMSREPORT/JSP/rpt/LoginAction.do?hmode=loginPage"
     Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
     Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

     Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

     'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
     With ieDoc
    .getElementById("userId").setAttribute "value", "rlbdgs"
    .getElementById("userPassword").setAttribute "value", "123"

    '~~> This will select the 2nd radio button as it is `0` based
    .getElementsByName("userType")(1).Checked = True

    .getElementById("hmode").Click
     End With
     Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
     Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

     'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
     ieApp.Navigate "http://cms.indianrail.gov.in/CMSREPORT/JSP/rpt/GeneralReportAction.do?hmode=drillDown25And26And30GeneralReport&kioskOrManual=K&val=26&wherePart=ZONE_CODE_C=-IR-&lobby=BSL&type=B&startDate=&endDate=&traction=ELEC"
     Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
     Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

     'get the table based on the table’s id
      Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
      Set ieTable = ieDoc.getElementById("report-table")    
     'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to the sheet
     If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
         Set clip = New DataObject
         clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
         clip.PutInClipboard
         Sheet1.Select
         Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
         Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
     End If

     'close 'er up
     ieApp.Quit
     Set ieApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Webpage source

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CREW BOOKED ON TA</title>

<link href="../styles/reportStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function DoNav(theUrl)
  {
    //alert(theUrl);
    document.location.href = theUrl;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="report-table">
    <!-- Table header -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="date" style="border:0px;" colspan="10">Print Date Time: <span>14-08-2014 13:30</span></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"  class="report-cris" style="text-align:center;">CRIS</th><th scope="col" class="report-heading" style="text-align:center;" colspan="8">VIGILENCE CONTROL DEVICE (VCD) IN LOCO NOT WORKING(SIGN OFF THROUGH KIOSK)(LOCO SHED WISE)(LAST 24 HOURS)<th scope="col"  class="report-cris" style="text-align:center;">CMS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border:none;">
                <th colspan="9" style="border-right:none;">
                                <span class="report-button" onclick="javascript:history.back();">BACK</span>
                                <span class="report-button" onclick="javascript:window.print();">PRINT</span>
                </th>
                <th style="border-left:none;text-align:right;"></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <table id="report-table">
    <thead>
        <tr style="border:none;" align="center">
                <th>S.No.</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>SIGNOFF DATE</th>
                <th>FROM</th>
                <th>TO</th>             
                <th>LOCO NO.</th>
                <th>BASE SHED</th>
                <th>RAILWAY</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>                              
                        <td>BINA1482</td>
                        <td >RAKESH KUMAR BAJPAI</td>
                        <td>14-08-2014 11:07</td>
                        <td >BINA</td>
                        <td>ET  </td>                       
                        <td>23551   </td>
                        <td>BRC</td>
                        <td>WR  </td>                       
                    </tr>                   

            </tbody>
</table>
* If duration for this report is last 24 hours or from and to date is same, then only last VCD reporting of the loco will be shown.
</body>
</html>
```

kindly suggest soluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look proper HTML to me to have two elements with the same id on the same page, but this would explain why ieDoc.all.Item("report-table") returns a collection. I guess the below shoud work - revert back to Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("report-table"), and then loop through the returned collection items.

Haven't been able to test this out though since the server looks down currently

```
 Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("report-table")

 'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to the sheet
 If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
    oHTML = ""
    For i = 0 To ieTable.Length - 1
        oHTML = oHTML & ieTable.Item(i).outerHTML
    Next i
    Set clip = New DataObject
    clip.SetText "<html>" & oHTML & "</html>"
    clip.PutInClipboard
    Sheet1.Select
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
    Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line above `Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("report-table")` should return a collection of all the "report-table" elements. Try and iterate through them. Something like this:

```
For Each ieTable In ieDoc.all.Item("report-table")
    'do stuff
Next ieTable
```

Also, starting with IE 11, `.all` will not be supported. MS recommends using `getElementById`.

Comment: Sorry, by mistake i have posted uncorrected code. ieDoc.all.Item is already repalced with getElementById as suggested by Mr. Siddharth. It is now edit also in the above mentioned code. Thanks.